# GKE autopilot cluster creation failure

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create composer environment using terraform in GCP and i could see that its getting failed in one of the project while creating the Kubernetes cluster in autopilot mode; its working fine in other 2 projects where we deployed in the same way.

So i tried to create autopilot kubernetes cluster in manual way as well and we are not able to track what is the issue with it as it shows the below error alone:

[k8s cluster creation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLuPS.png)

**Error while trying it from command line:**

```
gcloud container clusters create-auto test \
    --region europe-west2 \
    --project=project-id
```

Note: The Pod address range limits the maximum size of the cluster. Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr to learn how to optimize IP address allocation.
Creating cluster test in europe-west2... Cluster is being deployed...done.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create-auto) Operation [<Operation
 clusterConditions: [<StatusCondition
 canonicalCode: CanonicalCodeValueValuesEnum(UNKNOWN, 2)
 message: 'Failed to create cluster'>]
 detail: 'Failed to create cluster'
 endTime: '2022-05-31T20:00:07.8398558Z'
 error: <Status
 code: 2
 details: []
 message: 'Failed to create cluster'>
 name: 'operation-1654027061293-a14298fa'
 nodepoolConditions: []
 operationType: OperationTypeValueValuesEnum(CREATE_CLUSTER, 1)
 progress: <OperationProgress
 metrics: [<Metric
 intValue: 12
 name: 'CLUSTER_CONFIGURING'>, <Metric
 intValue: 12
 name: 'CLUSTER_CONFIGURING_TOTAL'>, <Metric
 intValue: 9
 name: 'CLUSTER_DEPLOYING'>, <Metric
 intValue: 9
 name: 'CLUSTER_DEPLOYING_TOTAL'>]
 stages: []>
 selfLink: 'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/locations/europe-west2/operations/operation-1654027061293-a14298fa'
 startTime: '2022-05-31T19:57:41.293067757Z'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 3)
 statusMessage: 'Failed to create cluster'
 targetLink: 'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/locations/europe-west2/clusters/test'
 zone: 'europe-west2'>] finished with error: Failed to create cluster
```

Comment: What does the logs say? How are you creating the cluster? Can you share the terraform steps you're using? You're missing some details which can make us just guessing instead of using facts

Comment: Also the image does not say more than your question so is not helpful at all

Comment: I am not getting any information in logs section which was so weird for me; its nothing to do with terraform scripts and its only related to kubernetes cluster creation even i tried to create the kubernetes cluster from command line in default network which is also not working.

Comment: Silly question, but did you enable the GKE API in the project where things are failing?

Comment: Yes GKE API is already enabled since there were two clusters already created in standard mode which is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service account “service-xxxxxxxx@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com” needs the role Kubernetes Engine Service Agent (roles/container.serviceAgent) which cased the k8s cluster creation to fail; after granting the permissions, we were able to create clusters